A question about Milo SDK subscriptionTransfer
I have a few related questions regarding Milo SDK subscriptionTransfer.

When a subscription transfer failed, we need re-create a new subscription and the monitored items, regarding the monitoredItems, can we use the old subscription to obtain the MonitoredItemCreateRequest? Say, convert the MonitoredItem saved in the old subscription to MonitoredItemCreateRequest? Or we should save the previous MonitoredItemCreateRequest in order to recreate them?

When the subscription is in transfer failed state, will the subscription be recycled by milo or we can still safely use the MonitoredItems?

The MonitoredItemCreateRequest has an parameter MonitoringParameters which takes a parameter called clientHandle. When we recreate the monitoredItems, shall we use the same clientHandle, or we can create and use new values as the clientHandle? If we can use the same clientHandle, are there any advantages for use the old one?

If the attempt to recreate the subscription, or monitoredItems failed in the onSubscriptionTransferFailed handler, what would be the suggested action?




It's not saved for you. Your application needs to keep enough of its own bookkeeping that you can create your Subscriptions and MonitoredItems again.

Not sure what you mean by "use them" - they no longer exist on the server.

You do not need to re-use the client handle. You are creating entirely new Subscriptions and MonitoredItems.

The same thing you would do if it failed while you tried to create it any other time. Presumably you have some idea of what you want to be subscribed vs. what is actually subscribed, and you retry again after some time.



Hi, Kevin, Thanks for the quick response. Since the onSubscriptionTransferFailed is called only once for each subscription failed transfer, based on your comments, we should add re-try and wait logic in the onSubscriptionTransferFailed handler? Before we retry, do we need run any resource cleaning? say clear the subscriptions? Would it be better if we disconnect the client then re-connect, or close/abandon the current client, and create a new one?

No, keep the client alive, you don't need a new one. The subscriptions are "cleared" on the Milo side, you just need to stop hanging onto references to them. I'm simplifying this a bit, but in our application we conceptually run a period task that checks to see if the subscriptions and items the application wants matches what actually exists, and if not, we attempt to create them.

Regarding my previous question #4. When attempt to recreate the subscription failed in the onSubscriptionTransferFailed handler, I should retry it as you suggested. Is there a timeout limit or other constraint for the onSubscriptionTransferFailed handler if I add the retry logic within the  the  handler, say, keep retrying until it succeeds, or I can save some failure statues, let the onSubscriptionTransferFailed  handler quickly return, and implement the re-try logic elsewhere. Any suggestions here? If the retry keep failing, will that cause crashing on the milo client/server side?

That might be okay, the callback is at least made asynchronously and won't block the Session state machine: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/d73a2165b9b3cf9f9cb0dd8311c19e2adab03863/opc-ua-sdk/sdk-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/opcua/sdk/client/session/SessionFsmFactory.java#L1042-L1055
